# Redirect all requests on Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect

I want to redirect ALL requests sent to my Tomcat server, e.g.

```
https://www.example.com{/xyz}
```

to a central login page, like this (url-encoded):

```
https://www.example.com/login?callback=https://www.example.com{/xyz}
```

Is this possible with Tomcat?

If not, I assume it can be done with Apache proxy? If so, what would the solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why no one responds to such simple questions to point in the right direction...

Yes, it's possible with Apache web server as a reverse proxy. Apache's `conf` file should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    . . . . .
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/login?callback=%{REQUEST_URI}
    . . . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

where `^` denotes that all requests should be rewritten with what follows.